# Regular Expression to find jQuery template tags

Tags: c#, regex, jquery-templates

I'm looking for the C# regular expression to find jQuery template tags. We have a editor where people can design their own letter and i need to replace those tags with the actual value.

Here's an example:

```
Welcome {{Name}} to our webshop. Your last visited our website on {{LastVisit}}
```

On the server i would like to search the posted content for these tags, something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Report report)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> tags = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    var matches = Regex.Matches(report.Content, @"\{{2}(?'tagname'[^{}]+)\}{2}"); 
    foreach(Match match in matches){
      tags.add(match.Value, match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
    return View();
}
```

My Regex should return this:

- Name
- LastVisit

Hope you can help me out!

Comment: See my updated question. I'm not very good with these expressions, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this Regex:

```
@"\{{2}(?'tagname'[^{}]+)\}{2}"
```

that extract the tag name in the named group 'tagname'.
Use the [Regex.Matches()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) method to obtain all matches in the string you submit.

Comment: This works partly. In my example it returns: {{Name}} and {Name} and it should be: {{Name}} Name, {{LastVisit}} LastVisit

Comment: @RobAngelier the whole tag is contained in the Match.Value property

Answer (score 3):

This one will do the trick:

```
string text = @"Welcome {{Name}} to our webshop. Your last visited our website on {{LastVisit}}";
IList<string> results = new List<string>();
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, @"\{\{([\w]*)\}\}");
foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
    results.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = 'Welcome {{Name}} to our webshop. Your last visited our website on {{LastVisit}}';
text = text.replace('\{\{Name\}\}', theName).replace('\{\{LastVisit\}\}', theLastVisit);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimdotdotdot/zcsp5/1/

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm looking for the c# version. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
        string input = @"Welcome {{Name}} to our webshop. 
                         Your last visited our website on {{LastVisit}}";

        int startIndex = input.IndexOf("{{") + 2;
        int length = input.IndexOf("}}") - startIndex;
        var name = input.Substring(startIndex, length);

        startIndex = input.LastIndexOf("{{") + 2;
        length = input.LastIndexOf("}}") - startIndex;
        var lastVisit = input.Substring(startIndex, length);
```

This sample doesn't use Regex because it seems that this example can be parsed using string methods. This method always expects two bracketed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following: `\{{2}(\w+)\}{2}`

Use like so:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{{2}(\w+)\}{2}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match match = regex.Match(targetString);
while (match.Success) {
    for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++) {
        Group group = match.Groups[i];
        if (group.Success) {
            string templateItemValue = group.Value;
        } 
    }
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this will do the job.  Then all you need to do is populate the dictionary with the values you want and the replace will handle the hard work for you.

```
var replaces=new Dictionary<string,string> { {"Name","Bob"} , {"LastVisit","2012-01-01"}};
var regex=new Regex(@"\{\{(?<field>.*?)\}\}");

var report="Welcome {{Name}} to our webshop. Your last visited our website on {{LastVisit}}";
var result=regex.Replace(report,delegate(Match match) {
     return replaces.ContainsKey(match.Groups["field"].Value) ? replaces[match.Groups["field"].Value] : match.Value;
  });
```